# Does Sitecore XP 9.1 & Sitecore XC 9.0.2 use IdentityServer separately?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Since Sitecore XP 9.1 has just been released recently within the new authentication mechanism, it's a .NET core based on IdentityServer4. We all know Sitecore XC 9.0.2 also has its own IdentityServer. So my concerns are:

1. Do they have separately IdentityServer which is one for XP 9.1 and other for XC 9.0.2?
2. Or Sitecore XC 9.0.2 is ***incompatible*** with Sitecore XP 9.1? If so, Sitecore will release a new version of Sitecore Experience Commerce in order to work with Sitecore 9.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will start with your second question

Sitecore Commerce 9.1 is not compatible with 9.0.2 (https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/804595).
   XC compatible with 9.1 should be released after 1 month of XP release.

At Symposium they said commerce releases would follow about 1 month after product releases

If XP 9.1 and XC 9.0.2 are not compatible then the second question doesn't make sense.
 When 9.1 XC will be released, I expect to have just one identity server.